# pymongo stop scanning after a specified character in regex

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

i have mongodb records like this:

```
{ "_id" : "age_calculator-python|513216a576b99c26fb004e4d", "status" : "BADGE" }
{ "_id" : "age_calculator|5127d91376b99c457e000246", "status" : "BADGE" }
{ "_id" : "age_calculator|51381ef276b99c5b16002330", "status" : "BADGE" }
{ "_id" : "based|514f525c76b99c2ff7000398", "status" : "BADGE" }
{ "_id" : "binary_search-javascript|514f525c76b99c2ff7000398", "status" : "BADGE" }
```

i want to find records having only 'age_calculator' using regular expression($regex).
i did something like this:

```
db.collection.find({status:'BADGE', "_id" : {'$regex': '^age_calculator'})
```

i want get results for only `age_calculator` but above query even include `age_calculator-python`.

How to overcome this?
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a dollar at the end of your regular expression, meaning 'end':

```
db.collection.find({status: 'BADGE', '_id': {'$regex': '^age_calculator$'})
```

Though, to be fair, matching a regular expression begin to end without any funky matching things is more like an exact match:

```
db.collection.find({status: 'BADGE', '_id': 'age_calculator'})
```

As Sammaye points out, you could also mean something like the following:

```
db.collection.find({status: 'BADGE', '_id': {'$regex': '^age_calculator\\|'})
```

This would match anything *starting* with 'age_calculator|', including the pipe.

Comment: Hmm he has a `|` at the end of the caption, not sure if that is intentional or not but might be good to add the regex for not matching the entire `_id` string but instead matching to the end of the pipe